# d3 concept question, why/when do I need to use url()?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I have a question about the concept & usage of url command within attr argument in d3.

I assume the reason for using 'url' is bringing attribute information already made to the newly 
defined element. 
Is it a fixed syntax only for making clip-path in d3?

I haven't seen any other cases using 'url' to assign attribute of an element.
In the following url('#clip'), 
Is it 
bringing **everything after .attr('id','clip') argument?**

```
  var clip = Svg.append("svg").append('clipPath')
      .attr("id", "clip")
      .append("rect")
      .attr("width", width )
      .attr("height", height )
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 0);

  // Color scale: give me a specie name, I return a color
  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(["setosa", "versicolor", "virginica" ])
    .range([ "#440154ff", "#21908dff", "#fde725ff"])

  // Add brushing
  var brush = d3.brushX()                 // Add the brush feature using the d3.brush function
      .extent( [ [0,0], [width,height] ] ) // initialise the brush area: start at 0,0 and finishes at width,height: it means I select the whole graph area
      .on("end", updateChart) // Each time the brush selection changes, trigger the 'updateChart' function

  // Create the scatter variable: where both the circles and the brush take place
  var scatter = Svg.append('g')
    .attr("clip-path", "url('#clip')")
```

If url is for bringing information after 'id' argument or 'class',
the code below should work but it's not working.

**what does 'url( )' do exactly?**

```
  var rects = svg.append('rect')
   .attr('id','recta')
  .attr('x',50)
  .attr('y',50)
  .attr('width',100)
  .attr('height',100)
  .style('fill','red')

  var rects2 = svg.append('rect',"url(''#recta')")
  console.log('a')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
var clip = Svg.append("svg").append('clipPath')
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", 200)
  .attr("height", 200)
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 0);
var scatter = Svg.append('g')
  .attr("clip-path", "url('#clip')")
```

Translates into this:

```
<svg>
   <clipPath id="clip">
      <rect width="200" height="200" x="0" y="0">
   </clipPath>
   <g clip-path="url('#clip')">
</svg>
```

So that's a `g` element with attribute `clip-path` defined by the contents of `#clip`.

Now this:

```
var rects = svg.append('rect')
  .attr('id','recta')
  .attr('x',50)
  .attr('y',50)
  .attr('width',100)
  .attr('height',100)
  .style('fill','red')
var rects2 = svg.append('rect', "url('#recta')")
```

Translates into:

```
<svg>
   <rect id="recta" x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100" style="fill: red">
   <rect>
</svg>
```

The parameter is just ignored.

More information on URL linking https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/linking.html